# Postfix: forward all mails from all addresses except one

Tags: ubuntu, email, email-server

I have one email `Washington@city.com` I've made the following rule in a forward table: `@city.com Washington@city.com`

That means mails for any address (`Chicago@city.com, Boston@city.com etc.`) with the domain `city.com` I'll receive at `Washington@city.com`. I like it but I want **to reject** mails that were intended for email `Miami@city.com`

Is it possible?

I'm using Postfix/Dovecot with MySQL on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: You want to reject any mail to Miami or just do not redirect them to you ?

Comment: Hi, Dom! I want to reject any mail to Miami. For instance, with a code 451 like this address does not exist but any other do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additionally to adding a forward table, you will need to add a smtpd_recipient_restrictions rule , for check_recipient_access:hash:/etc/postfix/rejected_destination , and fill that file /etc/postfix/rejected_destination, and run postmap over it (and service postfix reload after all changes)

You may check doc on http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions

Comment: Thank you so much, Xavy! Is it possible to make thru MySQL? Can you provide an example, please?

Comment: I'm not sure, all my experience with postfix is against LDAP directories, but I guess it should be possible:

Comment: Thank you, Xavy! In a case of interesting I found an article with the instruction how to make it thru a mysql db. Looks familiar if you met the mysql set up before. Here is a link: https://kitt.hodsden.org/blog/2014/06/postfix_check_recipient_access_mysql